# System.InvalidOperationException: 'El idioma de la gramática no coincide con el idioma del reconocedor de voz.' en VB.NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: vb.net, vb

Hola a todos he estado desarrollando un programa de reconocimiento de voz en visual studio 2019 con vb.net framework 4.7.2 este es el codigo:

```
Imports System.Speech
Imports SpeechLib
Imports System.Speech.Recognition
Public Class Form3
Dim speech As SpVoice = New SpVoice()
Dim WithEvents Rec As New Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine
Dim synth As New Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim Prueba As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-MX")
Dim Gramatica As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsDocument
Dim Regla As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRule("Hola")
Dim Lista As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsOneOf("Hola", "Como estas?")
Regla.Add(Lista)
Gramatica.Rules.Add(Regla)
Gramatica.Root = Regla
Rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
Rec.LoadGrammar(New Recognition.Grammar(Gramatica))
Rec.RecognizeAsync()
End Sub
Private Sub Reco_Recognized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Speech.Recognition.RecognitionEventArgs) Handles Rec.SpeechRecognized
Select Case e.Result.Text
Case "Hola"
speech.Speak("Hola", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync)
Case Else
speech.Rate = 0
speech.Speak("No le entendi señor", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync)
End Select
End Sub
Private Sub Reco_RecognizeCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizeCompletedEventArgs)
Rec.RecognizeAsync()
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Rec.Dispose()
synth.Dispose()
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
Me.Hide()
Form1.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

Sin embargo aparece el siguiente error:
[image: Este es el error que me salta]

Rec.LoadGrammar(New Recognition.Grammar(Gramatica)) Esta es la linea donde me salta el error

System.InvalidOperationException: 'El idioma de la gramática no coincide con el idioma del reconocedor de voz.' Este es el error que me salta, ya intente agregarle los recursos globales de idioma de español mexicano que es idioma por defecto de mi computadora sin embargo no me funciono y no se como resolverlo

Agradeceria mucho que me ayudaran a resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

Soy nuevo en StackOverflow, asi que no puedo comentar ni aqui ni en el post en ingles que note que tambie hiciste, solo puedo responder aqui.

Te iba a comentar que yo, que en estos ultimos dias he estado viendo temas relacionados a STT y TTS, tambien llegue al mismo problema que tu hace unas horas y no llegue a una solucion concreta aun.

En mi caso, la excepcion me sale al querer correr el programa que se muestra en este tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgX3jYgn3-o&ab_channel=Pillazo, en cuya descripcion esta este link con el codigo: https://pastebin.com/cCYYDC8f

El programa lo corri, al igual que tu, en una Windows Forms App VB.NET con el Framework 4.7.2 en VS2019 y obtuve este resultado.

Instrucccion previa al error donde agregue un PRINT:
[image: Ahi se que ve que el ATRIBUTO que imprimo que es un STRING, practicamente es una cadena vacia: ""]

Luego de ello me sale el error o exception:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segun la lista de links que consulte y que dejare abajo, el error me sale porque el "string del idioma del documento de la gramatica" que se imprime como cadena vacia "" es distinto de la forma en la que se representa el idioma actual de mi configuracion de VOZ:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como se deberia representar el idioma actual. Intente con "en-US", "eng", "english", etc y nada.

Si hubiera una forma de saberlo, podria ser util porque ese atributo que pongo en el PRINT permite get/set, o sea permite asignar y consolo cambiar ese STRING se podria cambiar el idioma de la gramatica de "" al idioma configurado en VOZ. Asi serian iguales y ya no saldria el error.
Pero no se como obtener ese atributo de ello... Segun los links, en apps UWP hay clases y atributos que permiten saber y cambiar el idioma configurado en VOZ, pero, yo, al igual que el pata del tutorial y al igual que tu, buscaba lograr el objetivo mediante una Windows Forms APP, y ya que en mi lectura no encontre respuesta, creo que en este tipo de app ni tampoco en WPF se podria obtener el string del idioma actual configurado en la seccion VOZ.
¿Se podra con cmd quizas o con otra forma?

OJO: No digo que debas dejar de usar Windows Forms y en vez de ello usar UWP, lo que digo es que algo que nos podria ayudar con este error que tenemos en Windows Forms, es una app UWP para obtener un String del idioma actual que tenemos configurado en la seccion VOZ.

Disculpa si alargue mucho este post pero preferi esto en vez de ser breve ahorita y luego enviarte toda esta historia por correo, ya que planeaba dejarte mi correo para que me contactes. Facil nos podemos ayudar en algo con este error medio raro y que al pata del tutorial no le sale. Ademas que el tema de Speech tambien puede ser pesado y mas aun en VB o VBA, en lo cual me interesaria usar el SAPI y ello no se si es tan directo como hacerlo en C#.

Con esto, me despido esperando alguna respuesta tuya (Y)
O, en todo caso, solo alguna pregunta si algo de aqui no se entendio. Saludos.

Aqui dejo opcionalmente la lista de links que consulte por si sirve de inspiracion (varios estan en ingles):
https://pastebin.com/SQS79wqP

Comment: Mi correo es el siguiente:

Comment: rickbravo1204@gmail.com

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, por favor, pasa las imágenes a formato de texto, pues una imagen no es reproducible, puedes leer [¿Es adecuado sugerir el cierre de preguntas que poseen imágenes para compartir código?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5047/es-adecuado-sugerir-el-cierre-de-preguntas-que-poseen-imágenes-para-compartir-c/5050#5050), donde hablamos también de este tema.

Comment: Hola RickMB mucho gusto gracias por contestar he logrado resolver el problema ya me sirve el reconocedor te pasare un link que me ayudo a resolver el problema y creo que te podra ser muy util, muchas gracias por contactarte conmigo. Este es el link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012639/how-can-i-fix-language-for-the-grammar-does-not-match-the-language-of-the-speech/17029584#17029584